# Number not printing to msgBox

Tags: autohotkey

When I run this code out1 outputs the correct value, but out2 doesn't even produce one. Why is this?

```
F9::
loopCount:=0

;Duration calc
InputBox, num1, Input, Input Value
loopCount:=num1/14

out1:=(loopCount*18900)
out2:=(loopCount*24500‬)

msgBox, %out1% to %out2%
ExitApp
return
```

I have tried making the numbers floating point by adding decimal points but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after rewriting. I have no words.

[image]